# XSLT - how to sort multiple elements by different attribute values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort an xml document in groups. My sample xml is below:

```
<a>
    <b sortKey="e"></b>
    <b sortKey="b"></b>
    <d sortKey="b"></d>
    <d sortKey="a"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

I'd like to sort all the `b`s and all the `d`s separately. `b` and `d` may have different sort keys.

I tried many different options based on what I've seen here and other places, but they either only give me the elements that are sorted, or give me the sorted elements + the rest of the elements.

This is one of my attempts:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='b']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                        <xsl:sort select="@sortKey" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='d']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                        <xsl:sort select="@sortKey" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This sorted *all* of the elements with an attribute `sortKey`, not the `b`s and `d`s separately.

I'm a noob with XSLT. so any help is much appreciated

ETA: My desired xml is like this

```
<a>
    <b sortKey="b"></b>
    <b sortKey="e"></b>
    <d sortKey="a"></d>
    <d sortKey="b"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

Comment: Will the **b** and **d** elements always be adjacent to each other? Or could you have b,d,b,d for example? (If so, how would you like the output to look then?)

Comment: They may not always be adjacent to each other. The output should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="b">
            <xsl:sort select="@sortKey"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="d">
            <xsl:sort select="@sortKey"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::b or self::d)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was missing the last line in the template `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::b or self::d)]"/>` so I was getting unsorted doubles. Thanks!